# How to add a "click" handler to a button which is a part of control template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have a control template:
(1)

```
<Style x:Key="customItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <ToggleButton>
                    <Grid Width="260" Height="58">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="58"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="202"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{StaticResource image_resourse}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1"> Button text </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ToggleButton>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It is used to customize ListBoxItems like this:
(2)

```
<ListBox>
    ...
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource customItemStyle}">
    ...
</ListBox
```

I want to set `Click` handler of a Button which is inside that template when applying style to ListBoxItem.
(1) - code from styles file
(2) - code from some component definition file

How can I do this?

Comment: Can't you use command binding instead?

Comment: Is the template defined as a resource in same XAML file or somewhere else?

Comment: I'm thinking about rewriting it with command binding, but I want to try to do it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to define an `ICommand` on the template.  That way, you should have no trouble binding the handler to whatever code you need.

Start by subclassing `ListBoxItem`, and include the "ICommand" dependency property:

```
public class CommandListBoxItem : ListBoxItem 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonCommandProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CommandListBoxItem), null);
    public bool ButtonCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ButtonCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public CommandListBoxItem()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CommandListBoxItem);
    }
}
```

Now modify the control template to link the command to the button click:

```
<Style x:Key="customItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type custom:CommandListBoxItem}">
                <ToggleButton>
                    <Grid Width="260" Height="58">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="58"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="202"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{StaticResource image_resourse}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{TemplateBinding ButtonCommand}"> Button text </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ToggleButton>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And finally, bind the command property to a command in your view-model (or code-behind):

```
<ListBox>
    ...
    <custom:CommandListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource customItemStyle}" 
                               ButtonCommand="{Binding CommandFromViewModel}" />
    ...
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Is there any way to set "click" directly? I just want code like <BoxItem style.template.button.click="button1_click"/>

Comment: @Informhunter well... yes, if the control template is on the page/control where the handler method is defined.  But it sounds like you don't want to do that -- ie, your control template is shared across multiple pages.  So the question then becomes, how to pass the click handler to the control template.  There's not really enough detail in your question to say what the best way would be.  Using `ICommand` is a standard, and convenient approach, though.

Comment: In the `ControlTemplate`, instead of `Command="{TemplateBinding ButtonCommand}"` I had to do `Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, ButtonCommand}"` - other than that this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a slight variation to apply the style. Button_Click can be handled

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <ToggleButton>
                            <Grid Width="260" Height="58">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="58"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="202"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{StaticResource image_resourse}"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click">Button text</Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </ToggleButton>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

<Grid>       
        <ListBox >
            <ListBoxItem>0ABC</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>1ABC</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>2ABC</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Inside xaml.cs, button click can be handled

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("E hoooo");
 }
```

Comment: I want to add different handlers for different items. And I want to add them at the moment of item definition. Anyway thank you for your answer.